# How to get a glue crawler event state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I am following this doc https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-glue-job-run-end/ to setup an auto-trigger on `lambda` when `crawler` finishes. The event pattern I set on `cloudwatch` is:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "crawlerName": [
      "reddit_movie"
    ],
    "state": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  },
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Crawler State Change"
  ],
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ]
}
```

And I add a lambda function as target for this rule in cloudwatch.

I manually trigger the crawler but it doesn't trigger the lambda after it finished. From the crawler log I can see:

```
04:36:28
[6c8450a5-970a-4190-bd2b-829a82d67fdf] INFO : Table redditmovies_bb008c32d0d970f0465f47490123f749 in database video has been updated with new schema

04:36:30
[6c8450a5-970a-4190-bd2b-829a82d67fdf] BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog

04:37:37
[6c8450a5-970a-4190-bd2b-829a82d67fdf] BENCHMARK : Crawler has finished running and is in state READY
```

Does above log mean crawler finished successfully? How do I know why the lambda function is not triggered from crawler?

And how I can debug this issue? which log should i look at?

Answer (score 2):

Following works -

```
Cloudwatch Event Rule -

{
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Crawler State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}
```

Sample lambda -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:        
        if event and 'detail' in event and event['detail'] and 'crawlerName' in event['detail']:
            crawler_name = event['detail']['crawlerName']
            print('Received event from crawlerName - {0}'.format(crawler_name))

            crawler = glue.get_crawler(Name=crawler_name)
            print('Received crawler from glue - {0}'.format(str(crawler)))

            database = crawler['Crawler']['DatabaseName']
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error handling events from crawler. Details - {0}'.format(e))
        raise e
```

Here is screenshot -
[image: Adding Crawler Cloudwatch event rule]

Comment: I see your event pattern looks same as mine. I am trying to figure out why my lambda is not triggered. I wonder where is the configuration on your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I follow the link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-glue-job-run-end/ and it doesn't work.  I found it is due to the python script lambda in the link is not correct if you paste it directly.  Please have a check of your lambda.

The python lambda copied from link

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
response = client.start_job_run(JobName = 'MyTestJob')
```

We need to fix it as below:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  response = client.start_job_run(JobName = 'MyTestJob')
```